# Detect and change website language from browser language

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-translate

I am using Google Script :

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I want to change my website language from my browser language.
I changed my browser language to Arabic and this code works fine in Firefox browser by alerting a popup to change website language on top.
But the same process and code did not work in chrome browser.

Is there any issue with my code or is there anything else not working on chrome browser.

Comment: Not a good way to do things. Google translations are not always that great. The native language on some of my computers is russian and google butchers it. So despite having fluent english, I would be forced to read a butchered text.